# I have a dataset that contains few table names in its column tablename_. How can I select rows from the tables present in the dataset

Tags: sql, oracle, dynamic

Dataset (dataset with tablenames)

```
Tablename_ (column in dataset)
Table1
Table2
Table3
```

How to select rows from Table1

Any suggestions

Comment: Is it a sqlite3 Database? Can you please explain more?

Answer (score 2):

Well, the simplest option is to

```
select * from table1;
```

i.e. disregard what you have in `dataset`. What do you need it for, if you know which table you're interested in?

---

Anyway, one option is to create a function and return refcursor. This example returns data from the *first* table stored in `dataset`; you never explained why is `table1` *the one*, so - any is good, I guess. Or will you pass it as a parameter? Can't tell.

```
SQL> select * from dataset;

TABLENAME_
--------------------
DEPT
emp

SQL> create or replace function f_test
  2    return sys_refcursor
  3  is
  4    l_tab   dataset.tablename_%type;
  5    l_rc    sys_refcursor;
  6  begin
  7    select min(tablename_) into l_tab from dataset;
  8
  9    open l_rc for
 10      'select * from ' || l_tab;
 11    return l_rc;
 12  end;
 13  /

Function created.

SQL> select f_test from dual;

F_TEST
--------------------
CURSOR STATEMENT : 1

CURSOR STATEMENT : 1

    DEPTNO DNAME          LOC
---------- -------------- -------------
        10 ACCOUNTING     NEW YORK
        20 RESEARCH       DALLAS
        30 SALES          CHICAGO
        40 OPERATIONS     BOSTON


SQL>
```